# How can I load qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, qooxdoo

can someone let me know if I am loading my qooxdoo js framework correctly? My code:

My HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script src="script/qooxdoo.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
  <div>
    Hello World!
  </div>
  <script>
    alert(q("div").getHtml());
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I opened my .html file but i did not get any alerts as I should have...

I also saved the qooxdoo file as "qooxdoo.js" in the same folder as my main HTML file... please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <script src="script/qooxdoo.js"></script>
> ```
>
> I also saved the qooxdoo file as "qooxdoo.js" in the same folder as my main HTML file

Move the file to a subdirectory called `script` or change the src so it doesn't say `script/`.

Answer (score 0):

It is all documented in pretty much detail here: http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/website/tutorial_web_developers.html.

You need to put the downloaded script file on a path which is relative to your html file, if you don't use the version stored on a CDN (see links to documentation below).

In your example above, if your html file is for example c:\test\index.html, the way your code looks, the script file should be c:\test\script\qooxdoo.js.

If you want qooxdoo.js to live in the same directory as your html file, your  tag needs to look like this:

```
<script src="qooxdoo.js"></script>
```

One thing bothers me, however. Is your qooxdoo.js what you downloaded from http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5/framework/q-3.5.min.js or http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5/framework/q-3.5.js? I'm confused by the changed name. If your file is something else, you need to download the qx.Website file for q(...) to work - the other qooxdoo downloads don't provide this.

You might want to read this page: http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/getting_started.html, and continue from there in whatever direction you find fit for your purposes, for a better understanding of what qooxdoo is and what it provides - it's not just about web pages, and qx.Website does not include all qooxdoo functionality.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work, because your Qooxdoo application create the Site asynchron. at the moment you call the alert, there are no qooxdoo Elements rendered.

Do an generate like in the tutorial and start the index.html. open the console of the browser (F12) and you will the if all works fine.